# Multiple state objects to Socket.Begin*

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this class:

```
class NetworkManager {
    public void Connect(IPAddress address, int port, Action callback) {
        Socket socket = new Socket(...);
        socket.BeginConnect(address, port, r => EndConnect(r, socket, callback), null);
    }

    private void EndConnect(IAsyncResult r, Socket socket, Action callback) {
        //End the connection and call the callback method
    }
}
```

Is this method of sending multiple state objects good?

If I put the begin in a loop, would I still pass by the correct socket?

```
Socket socket;
for(...){
    socket = new Socket(...);
    socket.BeginConnect(address, port, r => EndConnect(r, socket, callback), null);
}
```

I feel like there should be a more correct way of doing it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work, by way of creating a capture-context that snags `socket` and `callback`. It'll get the job done, usually. However, you **MUST MUST** understand the scoping rules of capture-contexts, and know whether `socket` refers to a per-iteration variable vs a variable shared between iterations. For my money, for that reason it isn't worth risking here.

But other mechanisms exist:

- you can pass an explicit state object in as the last parameter to `BeginConnect`, and access as `r.AsyncState`; this allows you to do things like repeatedly using a single delegate instance to avoid allocations, but you would still need some kind of tuple to contain the socket and callback
- you can use `ConnectAsync`; this has the same advantages in terms of re-using the delegate and having a state object (this time known as `UserToken`), but you don't need to package the socket, because that is exposed as the `ConnectSocket` in the event-handler - but it needs a `SocketAsyncEventArgs` instance, so it doesn't gain you much over `BeginConnect` in terms of allocations, but it *does* mean you are using the most recent (and most efficient) API

Whether it is worth changing depends on how high-volume this is.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at ConnectAsync. For some reason I've always been using BeginConnect, time for some change I suppose.

Comment: @Ineentho just note the usage of the `Socket.*Async` methods: it returns a `bool`; if the return is `false`, it is being performed async, and the event-handler will be raised. If the return is `true` it was already performed ***sync***, and *will not* raise the event-handler - you need to call into the code yourself. This is to allow you to avoid stack-dives, especially in "read" code. Obviously "connect" is very unlikely to complete synchronously!